# What is the technical term for this GUI feature?

Tags: web-app

I am wanting to learn something new in JS, but I don't know the technical name for it to be able to look it up. What I want to do is make a GUI feature in a web page that allows the user to place images or text in a space and move it around. The key is though, wherever they leave the text/image is relative to where it shows up in a different blank web page. Could anyone tell me what that is called?

Example of what I am talking about: https://gyazo.com/8e8e222eef992cdf1204d6c5045b603c

Answer (score 1):

A *linked view* with *navigational slaving* is what I've known it as

http://www.mmi.ifi.lmu.de/lehre/ws0809/hs/docs/scherr.pdf - Section 2.2, 4th para

Comment: Thank you very much @mgraham, I will look into that. Does that term just define the relationship of moving one element and having it appear and move in a separate location, or would it also explain the type of "window/box" I would need to create to be able to place and move the elements around in?

Comment: No, that's really an implementation detail, the technique can apply to web pages, panels within the same web page, panels within a desktop app etc. For implementation (quickly, before we get told off for mentioning the i word on this forum) you should be looking at some mvc framework, the model being the coordinates, the views being the layout pane and the target web page

Comment: Ahh okay I understand. Thank you very much for the help. It's been a rough ride getting an answer for this.